# Stripe - PaymentIntents handleCardPayment() - how to catch JS errors?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I've writen my code based off the example provided by Stripe:

```
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
var clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement
  ).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Display error.message in your UI.
    } else {
      // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
    }
  });
});
```

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-handle-card-payment

The issue I'm having is, say for example I don't provide a value for `clientSecret`. When I submit the form I get this error in the console:

[image]

How can I catch this error (and other JS errors) and show the error in my UI? I tried catching it in the `then()` function but I think this is only for reporting errors in the API response.

Comment: So you are getting clientSecret from backend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured it. A simple `try / catch` is all that is needed.

```
try {
  stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement
  ).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Display error.message in your UI.
    } else {
      // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
    }
  });
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Promises. If **stripe.handleCardPayment** processes successfully it returns the return value as the first parameter. If it doesn't, it gets rejected and gets sent in the second parameter. You have to handle that like so:

```
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
var clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
stripe.handleCardPayment(
clientSecret, cardElement
).then(function(result) {
if (result.error) {
  // Display error.message in your UI.
} else {
  // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
}
},
function(err){
console.log('err:', err); // Handle your error here.
});
});
```